# AWS Node Lambda to send back binary image in response

Tags: node.js, image, lambda, binary-data

I am using an AWS Node Lambda to resize an image and send that image back in binary format, and I am not sure if I am handling this right or not. Basically, I want to send the binary data back in my response in a way that it can just be loaded without any front end changes. I have a perfectly good version working that returns base64 data, but how would I modify this to return binary instead?

Here is my resizing function:

```
function imageSizer(url, args) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    bufferRequest.get(url, args, function (err, res, body) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        reject(err);
      }
      const originalFormat = url.includes('png') ? 'png' : 'jpeg';
      let newSize = (args.exact === true)
        ? sharp(body).resize(args.width, args.height)
        : sharp(body).resize(args.width, args.height).max();
      newSize.toFormat(originalFormat)
        .toBuffer()
        .then((outputBuffer) => {
          const newImage = "data:" + res.headers["content-type"] + ";base64," + new Buffer(outputBuffer).toString('base64');
          resolve(newImage);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          reject(error);
        })
    });
  })
}
```

Here is my handler:

```
function handler(event, context) {
    imageSizer(event.url, event.queryStringParameters);
    .then((result) => {
      context.succeed({
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'},
        body: result
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      context.succeed({
        statusCode: 502,
        headers:    { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body:    `Error sizing image ${error}`
      });
    })
}
```

As mentioned, this works fine for base64 but I am unsure what changes to make to `const newImage =` to send back binary data the browser can use to load the image.

Answer (score 0):

I went with this solution:

Change:

```
        .then((outputBuffer) => {
          const newImage = "data:" + res.headers["content-type"] + ";base64," + new Buffer(outputBuffer).toString('base64');
          resolve(newImage);
        })
```

To:

```
        .then((outputBuffer) => {
          resolve(outputBuffer);
        })
```

This returns the buffer in binary format, without having to do anything ourselves.